# How to expand a cardView to show hidden elements in android with a dropping animation?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, android-cardview

I am beginner in android animations and therefore, am wondering exactly how can I implement something like expand a cardView to show hidden options or elements.

For example: a post in social networking, we have a cardView holding the post info. it also has likes and comments buttons/options. When user taps on comments button the view should expand a little say certain height and show the comments and shrink back when the same button is tapped again.

I am listing my posts using **RecyclerView** in a **Fragment** using a **CardView**. I am looking for a soft animation along with expanding and shrinking back to original place or size.

Below is a screenshot that might help you understand what exactly I want:

[image]

How to do this? Will you please provide me a small snippet of code?

Comment: try `ExpandableLayout` to achieve this. Check https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout.

Comment: You can try foldable cardview https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android

Comment: What if you simply set CardView's height to wrap_content, and set android:animateLayoutChanges=true, and then just show/hide part of layout inside?

Answer (score 0):

use wrap content as height of **cardview** and use **textview** inside it below title, so on click make the textview **visible** and **invisible**.

And use **android:animateLayoutChanges=**"**true**" in **parent** **layout**.